# How to update form after it has started?

Tags: c#, python, .net, winforms, ironpython

Is it possible to update the winform after it has started.

for example.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System")
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import (Application, Form, StatusBar)

form = Form()
form.sb = StatusBar()
form.sb.Parent = form
form.sb.Text = "Demo"
Application.Run(form)
form.sb.Text = "Test"
```

I am able to see "Demo" but not the "Test".

How to change the status bar after Application.Run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add code into the load event

```
 private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       sb.Text = "Test";
      Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

Call do events to force a repaint of the form.

**VB**

```
Private Sub Form_Load(Byval Sender As Object, Byval e As EventArgs)
      sb.Text = "Test"
      Application.DoEvents()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks...wasn't sure whether it was vb or c# from the syntax in the question :)

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand c#. The code is ironpython

Answer (score 1):

`Application.Run(form)` starts a standard application loop on the current thread. That means the line `form.sb.Text = "Test"` won't actually do anything until the form is closed. You can show the form by using `form.Show()`, and it would be possible to update it then.

You could do one of two things. First, as Wheels73 suggested, add an event handler on the form load event. You can accomplish that with the following lines.

```
def form_load(sender, e):
    sender.sb.Text = 'Test'

form.Load += form_load
Application.Run(form)
```

You could also create a class for the form and add event handlers in there. I would recommend giving this a read: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/winforms/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `me.refresh()` or `form.refresh()`?